# Translates to, as, or into with idioms?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Which word should one use -- "to", "as", or "into", or another word or phrase-- in sentences such as this one: "[Idiom] translates [to, as, into] [translation]? For example, "*Piece of cake*" translates [to, as, into] *easy task*." Or is there a better word choice than "translate"?

Comment: can you provide some context? Is this about two different human languages; computer programming languages; metaphors; chemistry?

Comment: @JeffShaller All of the above, except chemistry. I would also add idioms.